# Correct meaning of 'astute' in the sentence given

Tags: meaning-in-context, definition

I have never heard of or use the word 'astute', and I couldn't quite understand the correct meaning of it in the sentence below.

> I manage resources under my control with astute efficiency, and lead the way with the highest level of competence.

The sentence is referred from U.S. Air Force's creed.

Most of the dictionaries describe the meaning of 'astute' as 'clever' or 'smart' in the context of politics or business.

The word seems to have an expression of negative connotation, which, if true, would not be appropriate in the sentence above.

Could you please explain the meaning of 'astute' and its connotation?

Comment: Astute doesn't necessarily bear a negative connotation. In your sentence I think it means showing a clever awareness and resourcefulness in practical matters. So the phrase "astute efficiency" means 'acting effectively originated from being fully aware of your surrondings and finding practical ways to deal with problems'

Comment: @Azad Thanks for your explanation! It helped me a lot.

Comment: Any time pal. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple search for "**astute** meaning" shows

> having or showing an ability to accurately assess situations or people and turn this to one's advantage.